# Consulate asked for my I-94 even though I've never been to the US

Tags: usa, air-travel, georgia-country, i-94, us-airways

Three weeks ago, my family was at the US Embassy in Tbilisi, Republic of Georgia (not a state in the USA) for an interview. The interviewer left our papers and pulled out a sheet of paper stating that we would receive an email asking us to receive the I-94 forms. After entering our information (name, surname, passport number) on the I-94 site, the site displayed: "Record not found for traveler." I then wrote a letter to the US Border Department on this site: https://help.cbp.gov and they wrote me that the I-94 could not accept a person who had never been to the US (we have never been; my father has lived there for years).

I wonder why the interviewer asked for this form and what to do in this case? I also sent this question to the embassy, but due to the many letters they have received, they have not been able to answer me for one week already.

The email I received from the consulate is as follows:

> Please be informed that your cases have been refused under INA section
> 221(g) and they are undergoing administrative processing pending the
> submission of the following document:  • Form I-94, Arrival/Departure
> Record; (Visas 92 only)
>
> Some visa applications require further administrative processing,
> which takes additional time after the visa applicant's interview by a
> Consular Officer. Most administrative processing is resolved within 60
> days. When administrative processing is required, the timing will vary
> based on individual circumstances of each case.  Please fill in the
> forms online, print them out and provide them through the courier
> service TNT Express.

Comment: What kind of visa are you applying for?  Did your application indicate that you have never been to the US?  Have you received the e-mail message that the interviewer mentioned?  If so, what exactly did it say?

Comment: The I94 form is what is filed when you enter the US. Not been to the US, no I94, that’s quite normal. I find it surprising they would need you to get that info, they should have access to that directly (and in such a way they can trust the data). Maybe they meant you should start filling out the I94 forms? Having the exact text of the email would indeed help.

Comment: Did you call the embassy?

Comment: How do you intend to enter the US? Are you sure they weren't asking you to *apply* for I94?

Comment: Reply for phoog: I applying for immigration visa and The letter I received did not mention the name of the interviewer.                          Reply for jcaron: Maybe I do not rule it out.  Please see the photo of email and rate the situation.                                         Reply for DHClay:   Yes I have been calling for a week and they are asking me to wait for a reply to the email

Comment: Reply for littleadv:   Maybe but when I click on the i94 site, apply for i94: https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/apply-document.     It written: You do not need to use the website to apply for an I-94; you will be provided an electronic I-94 at the air or sea port of entry by the CBP Officer. But the embassy asks me to bring this form

Comment: What kind of visa are you applying for? And what was the planned itinerary? How did you intend to enter the US? Directly by air, or through a land border (i.e. from Canada or Mexico)? Note that even if you say you will enter via a lane borde to apply for a provisional I94, you need a visa number to get it… there’s something really weird here.

Comment: Yes this doesn't make much sense on their part, since you don't have, and can't have, a form I-94. This is a wild guess, but is it possible they really want to see a copy of your father's form I-94? Unfortunately, there is little we can do but guess; you'll really need an answer from them as to what documents they want from you exactly.

Comment: The "Visas 92" bit kind of suggests it is plausibly your father's I-94, from when he first entered the US, that they are interested in. This seems silly since they'll have access to everything that could tell them in your father's USCIS file, but maybe there is a regulation that says that a copy of that I-94 needs to be included for the V-92 application to be complete, or something?

Comment: V92 is for derivative asylees following to join the principal asylee. Is that the case for you?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, let's define what an I-94 is.  Historically, an I-94 was the piece of paper obtained when a non US citizen/permanent resident entered the US, which contained details of the period of stay the person had been granted inside the US, the visa class they were entering under, etc.  Upon leaving the country, the I-94 was returned to the US government (generally by being collected by the airline who then gave them to the government).

With very few exceptions, you can not have an I-94 when you are outside of the US, as it is collected when departing the US.  It is only something that a person inside the US would have.

Now days, I-94's are almost always electronic, and there is a website that can be used to obtain a copy of your CURRENT I-94 record - but again, only if you are physically inside the US at the time.  Once you leave the US, the I-94 ends.  After that point you can view your I-94 history, but you can not view your current I-94 as you no longer have one.

So a consulate outside of the US asking someone to provide their own I-94 simply makes no sense - even if the person had previously visited the US, they would no longer have an I-94 whilst they were outside of the US. Which means that's clearly not what you were asked to provide.

Your rejection notice refers to "Visas 92".  Visas 92 refers to a Follow-to-Join Asylum Visa. This is where one member of a family is granted asylum in the US, and then a spouse or child may also be allowed to "Follow-to-join" that person in the US.  "Follow-to-join" cases can only be considered where the original applicant is already physically in the US.

Hopefully you can already see where this is headed. The family member that has been granted asylum is already in the US - and thus has an I-94.  It is almost certainly this I-94 that you are being asked to provide. The consulate will require this as proof that the person is in the US, and in order to view their immigration status in the US.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that an asylee's I-94 will not have been issued by CBP, or, [if it has been, it will be a paper form; in either case it won't be available on the I-94 website](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1696?language=en_US) ("Most asylum seekers should have received a handwritten or stamped I-94 upon entering the U.S., and may not be able to retrieve I-94 information online").